# Can 32-bit SPARC V8 application run on 64-bit SPARC V9?

Tags: performance, cpu-architecture, 32bit-64bit, sparc

I have few benchmark application complied for SPARC V8 32-bit architecture. I used them for performance evaluation of SPARC 32-bit processor. However, few application fall short of in performance. I want to test the performance with a 64-bit SPARC V9 architecture ( like OpenSPARC T1/T2). My question is will the compiled binaries for the 32-bit SPARC V8 architecture run in SPARC V9 architecture without any modifications? Are the binaries in both architectures compatible?

Answer (score 5):

Presuming that you are using the same Operating System though perhaps at a newer version. Then yes. Solaris Sparc is very binary backward compatible. Each revision of the Sparc architecture was designed with this in mind.

Things you should keep in mind:

- Sparc v7 is the lowest common denominator however in practice Sparc v8 wil cover 99% of machines.
- Sparc v7 usually lacks hardware floating point so it will be slower in most all cases for that, though it was sometimes added as an accelerator.
- Sparcv8 code will be faster in some cases than Sparcv9 64bit code due to pointers being half as large.
- the optimal code for a Sparc v9 is most often Sparc v8+ which is basically 32bit code with some extensions that for the most part only 64bit machines have. Due to this most all 64bit Sparc Operating Systems ship most code as 32bit with some 64bit code where it needs access to more ram or 64bit only extensions for performance such as with software based encryption.
- While the ISA for Sparc is quite static performance is not.. for instance Sparc T1 Niagra CPUs are dog slow for any single threaded task but run like champs when you load them with many tasks . However some of the Fujitsu Sparc chips probably rival Intel for speed in every area. Also I wouldn't be the least bit supprised if some of the older Ultra workstations were a lot faster than Niagra T1/T2 for single to a couple threads. Once you get into the area of many threads a Niagra style CPU will start to shine.

So remember Sparc v7 , Sparc v8 and Sparc v9 are not chip architectures they are Instruction Set Architectures. The performance for Sparc is mainly dependent on the implementation of the CPU Architecture. Thew newest Sparc processors from Oracle are improving single threaded performance much more than in the past something to keep in mind as well (even if they would burn a hole in your wallet the size of Texas).

If your performance is falling short and you are designing a FPGA based CPU seriously consider improving your CPU design to increase throughput.

Comment: Sparc v7 had floating point support - however, the FPUs were on a separate chip. Not sure if you could also have Sparc v8 CPUs without built-in FPUs. What Sparc v7 did not have was a multiplication or division instruction; instead, Sparc v7 had an instruction that processed one (?) bit of a product or quotient so you had to call this instruction 32 times for a 32x32=64 multiplication.

Comment: True it would be more correct to say v7 has no standardized FPU... and no hardware mul/div. I also updated my incorrect summary of 32bit vs 64bit... the main thing that changes with 64bit code is pointer size.

Answer (score 1):

Terminology confusion ...

SPARC is a little bit like ARM. You have:

- the SPARC chip architectures (as far as they were developed by Sun Microsystems / now Oracle) are named `sun4[a-z]`; actual tapeout only for `sun4`, `sun4c`, `sun4d`, `sun4m`, `sun4u` and `sun4v`
  This corresponds to `ARM[1-9]`, `ARM11`, `Cortex-...`, i.e. evolution of the CPU design.
- SPARC CPU instruction sets are 'versioned' - `sparcv7`, `sparcv8`/`sparcv8+`, `sparcv9`; some of these are 32bit, `sparcv9` is 64bit
  This corresponds to `ARMv[0-9]`, revs on the instruction set.
- operating modes (32bit / 64bit on SPARC);
  ARM here has Thumb[2], 32bit ARM and ARMv8/64bit.

In this context, `sparcv9` is the 64bit instruction set and therefore requires the 64bit operating mode; the same binary encoding might have different meanings in 32bit/64bit modes and therefore `sparcv7/8` code will not run in 64bit mode.

Still, `sun4u` and `sun4v` CPU architectures support the 32bit mode - with a `sparcv8+` instruction set plus a few extensions, and `sparcv8` in itself being a superset of `sparcv7`.
Sun/Oracle pride themselves of their binary backwards compatibility; all current SPARC CPUs should run existing 32bit binary code without problems. I assume, in this context, that you're talking about Solaris binaries ?

Comment: This is not quite correct the sun4 names are platform names, and are not directly associated with the CPUs in question for example sun4 sun4m and sun4d are all use extremely similar CPUs (especially m and d). They are however evolutions of the platform design c m and d coexisted more or less... at one point c as low end, m and midrange and d as high end. u is the original ultrasparc platform, and v is ultrasparc with virtualization. The acutal CPU architectures that compare to ARM 1-9 etc.. would are the less well known CPU arch names like microsparc and supersparc, with many other variations.