# What is EM_SPARC32PLUS for?

Tags: elf, sparc

I found that Linux and GNU Binutils define a special machine type `EM_SPARC32PLUS` in ELF header. Why is it needed? What makes SPARC V8+ so special that it can not use `EM_SPARC`?

I think there should be an important reason for new machine type, because it breaks compatibility with old programs, and all other architectures tend to use the old machine type as long as possible.

Comment: I would immediately suspect that it is a new, non-backwards-compatible instruction set. The same reason x86 and SPARC don't have the same machine type.

Comment: From wikipedia, `SPARC Version 8 (V8), an enhanced SPARC architecture definition, was released in 1990. The main differences between V7 and V8 were the addition of integer multiply and divide instructions, and an upgrade from 80-bit "extended precision" floating-point arithmetic to 128-bit "quad-precision" arithmetic. SPARC V8 served as the basis for IEEE Standard 1754-1994, an IEEE standard for a 32-bit microprocessor architecture.`. Doesn't seem like backward-incompatible revision.

Comment: That's referring to `V8`, not `V8 plus`.

Comment: As for me, v8+ (any UltraSPARC) has full set of atomic operations (actually, CAS), and true v8 chip (SuperSparc/HyperSparc from beginning of 1990s) has only limited 24-bit swap. So, v8 and v8+ are different instruction sets, and v8+ has more instructions available. Any v9 chip can execute both v8 and v8+ code, but ancient SS10 can work only with true v8 code, but not with v8+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with [`elf-em.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/elf-em.h#L21), we see the following (cherry-picked) entries:

```
#define EM_SPARC        2
#define EM_SPARC32PLUS  18      /* Sun's "v8plus" */
#define EM_SPARCV9      43      /* SPARC v9 64-bit */
```

Some Googling led me to [this reference page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5267/bkazb/index.html) for Sun Studio 12, which says:

> v8plus
>
> Compile for the V8plus version of the SPARC-V9 ISA. By definition, V8plus means the V9 ISA, but limited to the 32–bit subset defined by the V8plus ISA specification, without the Visual Instruction Set (VIS), and without other implementation-specific ISA extensions.
>
> This option enables the compiler to generate code for good performance on the V8plus ISA.
>
> The resulting object code is in SPARC-V8+ ELF32 format and only executes in a Solaris UltraSPARC environment—it does not run on a V7 or V8 processor.
>
> Example: Any system based on the UltraSPARC chip architecture

It seems to be essentially the 32-bit version of the V9 architecture for the [UltraSPARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraSPARC).

See also:

- [Can 32-bit SPARC V8 application run on 64-bit SPARC V9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370517/can-32-bit-sparc-v8-application-run-on-64-bit-sparc-v9)

Comment: Makes sense. I thought `v8plus` means `v8` and newer.

Comment: @MaratDukhan I added a link you may find interesting too.

Comment: Thanks. `v8plus` seems like `x32` ABI on `x86-64`, but unlike `v8plus`, the `x32` ABI uses machine type `EM_X86_64` (same as `x86-64`) with file class `ELFCLASS32` to indicate 32-bit mode.

Comment: @MaratDukhan Good point. Based on your analogy, I tend to agree with you that defining a different machine type seems a bit "heavy". I'd like to find an old mailing list post or something indicating why they went this route. +1 on the interesting question, by the way.